# gitlab ci pipeline not fail when sonarqube fail

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I have integrated sonarqube on my application

**actual result**

testcase pass percentage fail in my sonarqube but gitlab ci pipeline success

**expected result**

when sonarqube is fail pipeline also getting same result

```
  sonarqube:
  stage: sonarqube
  image: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
  tags:
    - dedicated-runner1
  allow_failure: true # set allow_failure to false to stop pipeline on SonarQube analysis failure
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectName="${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" -Dsonar.projectKey="${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
```

Answer (score 0):

i had found solution

my sonar version 8.8 Community Edition

below added piece of add in your **sonar-project.properties**

```
# pass CI pipeline with warning.
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
sonar.qualitygate.timeout=1000
```

gitlab yml file

*allow_failure:false
[doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/devops-platform-integration/gitlab-integration/)

```
# sonarqube
sonarqube:
  stage: Sonar
  image: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
  tags:
    - dedicated-runner1
  allow_failure: false  # set allow_failure to false to stop pipeline on SonarQube analysis failure
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectName="${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" -Dsonar.projectKey="${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
```